# Translate xml string to Python list

Tags: python, xml, django, string, list

I am new to Python. I want to show this XML string as a list in a template.

```
xmlData = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<django-objects version="1.0">
<object model="task.task" pk="4">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="mission_id" type="IntegerField">2</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="5">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="mission_id" type="IntegerField">2</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="6">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New ask</field>
<field name="mission_id" type="IntegerField">2</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="7">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="mission_id" type="IntegerField">2</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object></django-objects> """
```

I just want to show this as a list.
I import cElementTree

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
```

I also did:

```
xmlList = ET.fromstring(xmlData)
```

but I don't know how to show it. I want to show something like this.

```
print xmlList.name
print xmlList.mission_id
print xmlList.parent_task_id
```

Please help me know the correct syntax for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code sample:

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET
xml = ET.fromstring(xmlData)

for child in xml.iter('field'):
    print child.tag, child.attrib, child.text
```

to iterate over all XML elements named `field` and print to the console their tag, attributes and text value.

Check out [`xml.etree` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) for more samples.

### Django view

In order to render parsed XML data as a view in Django application you need [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/views/) and [template](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/).

Assuming you have a Django application called `app` installed in your project.

`app/views.py`

```
from xml.etree import cElementTree as ET

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import Context, loader


def xml_view(request):
    xmlData = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <django-objects version="1.0">
    <object model="task.task" pk="4">
    <field name="name" type="CharField">foo</field>
    <field name="mission_id" type="IntegerField">1</field>
    <field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">20</field>
    </object>
    <object model="task.task" pk="7">
    <field name="name" type="CharField">bar</field>
    <field name="mission_id" type="IntegerField">2</field>
    <field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">10</field>
    </object></django-objects>"""

    xml = ET.fromstring(xmlData)

    fields = []
    for obj in xml.iter("object"):
        fields.append({'name': obj.find("field[@name='name']").text,
                       'mission_id': obj.find("field[@name='mission_id']").text,
                       'parent_task_id': obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text,
                       })

    t = loader.get_template('your_app/xml_view.html')
    c = Context({'elem_list': fields})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

`app/templates/app/xml_view.html`

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Mission ID</th>
        <th>Parent Task ID</th>
      </tr>
      {% for elem in elem_list %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ elem.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ elem.mission_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ elem.parent_task_id }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hank you so much... but i still cant get what i want to show.... i want to show table such as:

<table>
<tr>
<th>Name
<th>Mission ID
<th>Parent Task ID
<tr>
<td> {{ Name }}
<td> {{ Mission ID }}
<td> {{ Parent Task ID }}

Comment: Thank you Maciej Lach, I will try it... I really appreciate your help!